# Prove: $\theta(n^2)+O(n^3)\subset O(n^3)$

Tags: asymptotics

I believe that my understanding of this question is incorrect, so any help would be appreciated.

**The Question:**

Prove: $\theta(n^2)+O(n^3)\subset O(n^3)$

Note that for this problem, you are proving that the set of functions on the left hand side is a subset of the set of functions on the right hand side. The set on the left hand side is the algebraic sum of two sets (not the union): an element of the left hand side has the form $f(n)=f_1(n)+f_2(n)$, where $f_1(n)\in\theta(n^2)$ and $f_2(n)\in O(n^3)$

**My Question**:

Is it safe to assume that $n^2\in\theta(n^2)$ and $n^3\in O(n^3)$?

Thus, $f(n) = n^3 + n^2 $

$f(n) \in O(n^3)$

$n^3 + n^2 \leq cn^3$

$n+1 \leq cn$

$c \geq 2 $

$∴  f(n) ∈  O(n^3 )$ and $f(n) ⊆ O(n^3 )$

Comment: could you please specify what $\theta(n^2)$ is...

Comment: The only thing I was given is...

**f(n)=f_1 (n) + f_2 (n) & f_1 (n) ∈ θ(n^2) & f_2 (n) ∈ O(n^3 )**

Comment: what i mean is what does elements of $\theta(n^2)$ looks like??

Comment: It is not specified.

Comment: Usually $f\in\theta(g)$ is equivalent to (if not defined as) $f\in O(g)$ and $g\in O(f)$, if that helps.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, it stands for Big Theta Notation. In a sense, it is the average-time an algorithm will take to run. Or the average amount of iterations for which it will run.

Comment: @David : Oh, I am not familiar with that. Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, no problem. It is in the family of Big Oh and Big Omega. Check 'em out. It's interesting. I'm tempted to say he should have posted this in Stackoverflow, not Mathematics.

Comment: Is my assumption correct or are you all not certain?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to assume that $n^2\in\theta(n^2)$ and $n^3\in O(n^3)$. 
>   Thus, $f(n) = n^3 + n^2 $

is as valid as

> It is safe to assume that the murderer lives in California. You live in California, therefore you are the murderer.

I hope that if you served on a jury and heard the above argument, you'd find a flaw in it.

Anyway, suppose $f\in \theta(n^2)$ and $g\in O(n^3)$. The proof can proceed in two steps.

1. Show that $f \in O(n^3)$
2. From $f\in O(n^3)$ and $g\in   O(n^3)$ obtain that $f+g\in O(n^3)$

You don't need to know any formula for $f$ or $g$ to run the above argument.